# How to check multiple columns in Sqlite using Where clause?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to SqLite Databases and queries. I want to check where both latitude and longitude of a location is stored in the database. I am passing my latitude and longitude values from a activity to a function in my database class. I tried using

```
 c = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from savedlocation (where latitude = ? and 
   longitude = ?) ", new String[] {String.valueOf(latitude),String.valueOf(longitude)});
```

but it doesn't help.

Can anyone suggest me what modification in the code should I do.
My codes are as follows:

```
public int isUserAvailable(Double latitude)
{
 int number = 0;
Cursor c = null;
try
{
    c = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from savedlocation where latitude = ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(latitude)});

    if(c.getCount() != 0)
        number = c.getCount();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(c!=null) c.close();
}
return number;
 }
```

and I am calling the function using

```
 int n=db.isUserAvailable(latitude);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove parentheses form your query

```
c = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from savedlocation where latitude = ? and 
   longitude = ? ", new String[] {String.valueOf(latitude),String.valueOf(longitude)});
```